# Wait until async `EventCallback` will be fully executed in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

### Target

I have the TODO list-like application.
The algorithm adding of task is:

1. Once "Save new task" button clicked, display the blocking loading overlay

[image]

2. If task has been successfully submitted,
   2.1 Hide blocking loading overlay
   2.2 Clear the input fields
   2.3 Switch the "TaskManager" component to viewing mode

### Code

The parent component is `TasksManagementPageContent` and the `TaskManager` is the child component with viewing and editing modes.

```xml
<div class="TasksManagementPage-SpecificContent">

    <TaskManager 
        onInputtingDataOfNewTaskComplete=@onNewTaskEditingCompleted
        @ref=@taskManager
    />
    
</div>
```

According to the idea, the `TaskManager` does *not* submit the data to the data source (such as the database), it just displays the existing data passed via parameter in viewing mode and emits the inputted data in the editing mode.
The data submitting is being executed from `TasksManagementPageContent` component:

```cs
public partial class TasksManagementPageContent : ComponentBase
{
  
  private TaskManager taskManager = null!;
  
  private void beginInputOfNewTaskData()
  {
    this.taskManager.beginInputNewTaskData();
  }
  
  private async void onNewTaskEditingCompleted(CommonSolution.Gateways.ITaskGateway.Adding.RequestData requestData)
  {
    
    BlockingLoadingOverlayService.displayBlockingLoadingOverlay();

    try
    {
      await TasksSharedState.addTask(requestData);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

      await SnackbarService.displaySnackbarForAWhile(
        message: "The error occurred during the saving of new task data.",
        decorativeVariation: Snackbar.StandardDecorativeVariations.error
      );

      Debug.WriteLine(exception);
      return;

    }
    finally
    {
      BlockingLoadingOverlayService.dismissBlockingLoadingOverlay();  
    }
    
    this.taskManager.utilizeTaskEditing();
        
    await SnackbarService.displaySnackbarForAWhile(
      message: "The new task has been saved",
      decorativeVariation: Snackbar.StandardDecorativeVariations.success
    );
    
  }
}
```

The important thing that `TaskManager` must be reusable, so it must NOT know anything about parent including `TasksManagementPageContent`.

```cs
public partial class TaskManager : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
{
  
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter] 
  public required Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<
    CommonSolution.Gateways.ITaskGateway.Adding.RequestData
  > onInputtingDataOfNewTaskComplete { get; set; }
  
  private bool isViewingMode = true;
  private bool isEditingMode => !this.isViewingMode;
  
  private TextBox titleTextBox = null!;
  private TextBox descriptionTextBox = null!;
  
  private (
    ValidatableControl.Payload title, 
    ValidatableControl.Payload description
  ) taskControlsPayload;
  
    
  public TaskManager()
  {
    this.taskControlsPayload = (
      title: new ValidatableControl.Payload(
        initialValue: "", 
        validation: new TaskTitleInputtedDataValidation(),
        componentInstanceAccessor: () => this.titleTextBox
      ),
      description: new ValidatableControl.Payload(
        initialValue: "", 
        validation: new TaskDescriptionInputtedDataValidation(),
        componentInstanceAccessor: () => this.descriptionTextBox
      ) 
    );
  }
  
    
  public void beginInputNewTaskData()
  {
    this.isViewingMode = false;
  }
    
        
  public void utilizeTaskEditing()
  {
    
    this.isViewingMode = true;

    this.taskControlsPayload.title.Value = "";
    this.taskControlsPayload.description.Value = "";

  }
  
  private async void onClickTaskDataSavingButton()
  {

    if (ValidatableControlsGroup.HasInvalidInputs(this.taskControlsPayload))
    {
      ValidatableControlsGroup.PointOutValidationErrors(this.taskControlsPayload);
      return;
    }
    
        
    await this.onInputtingDataOfNewTaskComplete.InvokeAsync(
        new CommonSolution.Gateways.ITaskGateway.Adding.RequestData
        {
            Title = this.taskControlsPayload.title.GetExpectedToBeValidValue<string>(),
            Description = this.taskControlsPayload.description.GetExpectedToBeValidValue<string>()
        }
    );


  }
  
}
```

### Problem

Let us see what is happaning:

- `onClickTaskDataSavingButton` method invokes the `onInputtingDataOfNewTaskComplete` callback, the function-type parameter
- The `await` keyword will NOT wait until the method `onNewTaskEditingCompleted` of `TasksManagementPageContent` will complete - the `InvokeAsync()` will be executed almost instantly.
- `onNewTaskEditingCompleted` will call `utilizeTaskEditing` method of child `TasksManagementPageContent`

First, I don't want to see that this methodology is correct. It should be some solution with simpler data flow.

Anyway, it does not work: although the `utilizeTaskEditing` will be executed, the re-rendering of `TaskManager` will not be triggered so the switching to the viewing mode will not be.

It should be the multiple solutions.
First, if `await this.onInputtingDataOfNewTaskComplete.InvokeAsync` was wait until `onInputtingDataOfNewTaskComplete` actually be completed, it was the solution.

Other solutions are welcome but please keep the condition about `TaskManager` must NOT know anything about parent including `TasksManagementPageContent`.

Comment: replace `async void`  with `async Task` and try again.

Comment: @ℍℍ Works fine! Would you please to post the answer? I'll accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take his snippet:

> ... it does not work: although the utilizeTaskEditing will be executed, the re-rendering of TaskManager will not be triggered

The rerendering will be triggered but it competes with the activity it is supposed to show, and might run before that is completed.

You should always try to avoid `async void`.  All Blazor events support Task returning methods and that delivers a much more predictable sequence of events and rendering.